# C++11 array declaration example from 8.3.4p4 doesn't match gcc or clang?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a subset of an example from C++11 (same through to latest draft) 8.3.4p4  ([dcl.array]/4):

```
extern int x[10];                   // 1

int x[]; // OK: bound is 10         // 2

void f() {
    extern int x[];                 // 3
    int i = sizeof(x); // error incomplete type
}
```

gcc does not agree with the error and gives:

```
error: type mismatch with previous external decl of ‘int x []’
```

instead (at declaration 3).

clang compiles without error.

My intepretation would be that the example is well-formed.  Declaration 3 should link to declaration 1 and 2, and should therefore have type `array of 10 int`, and not `array of unknown bound int`.  So it should be complete at the sizeof.

Who is correct?  The standard, gcc or clang?

Comment: Maybe add compiler versions?

Comment: gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1), clang version 3.0-6ubuntu3

Comment: Ok. I tested it with clang 3.4 and it agrees with the sizeof fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

8.3.4/3 includes:

> Furthermore, if there is a preceding declaration of the entity in the same scope in which the bound was specified, an omitted array bound is taken to be the same as in that earlier declaration,

Since the declaration inside the function is not in the same scope as the global declaration that doesn't apply, and therefore does not grant permission to omit the array bound. I don't see any other text that would permit the omission either, and therefore the type of `x` in the `sizeof(x)` expression is incomplete.

Clang should not be accepting the code, gcc is rejecting it for the wrong reason, and the standard's example looks accurate to me.

Comment: Are you taking into account the extern specifier?  This links it to the previous two declarations.  All three declarations refer to the same object.

Comment: Testing with latest versions of gcc and clang it looks like the error agrees with the standard.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Yes, the `extern` declaration does simply redeclare the globally defined array and so refers to the same object, however that doesn't automatically mean that they all have the same status in terms of complete types.